# node - cordova . "unmet dependency"

Tags: node.js, cordova, installation

i tried to clean the cache and install it again but it says a warning unmet dependency

C:\Users\Ralph>npm cache clean

C:\Users\Ralph>npm install -g cordova

C:\Users\Ralph\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\Ralph\AppData\Roaming\npm
\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Ralph\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phoneg
ap\node_modules\connect-phonegap requires shelljs@'0.2.6' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Ralph\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phoneg
ap\node_modules\shelljs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.1.4
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Ralph\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phoneg
ap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman requires request@'2.22.0' but will
load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Ralph\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phoneg
ap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\request,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.21.0
cordova@4.2.0 C:\Users\Ralph\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── cordova-lib@4.2.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.
2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, unorm@1.3.3, semver@2.0.11, shelljs@0.3.0
, rc@0.5.2, dep-graph@1.1.0, npm@1.4.28, elementtree@0.1.5, xcode@0.6.7, through
2@0.6.3, npmconf@0.1.16, glob@4.0.6, plist@1.1.0, tar@1.0.2, request@2.47.0, d8@
0.4.4, cordova-js@3.7.3)

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Cordova cannot run on the latest version of Node because it actually requires v10.x of Node. So, here is how I avoided the *"Warning: unmet dependency"* when installing Cordova:

1. `> npm uninstall -g cordova`
2. [Use n](https://github.com/tj/n) ([nvm](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) for Windows) to downgrade an older version of Node (Windows users will need to downgrade and use):

   `> n 0.10.40`
3. `> npm cache clean`
4. `> npm install -g cordova`

If you want to install Ionic, then in step 4, call the npm command to directly install ionic (with no @latest) instead of cordova, like this:

4. `> npm install -g ionic`

Note: Linux / OSX users may need to prepend the npm commands with "sudo".